# How to make Ansible notice host is the same and avoid task collisions

Tags: ansible

My inventory files keep the same logical number of hostsbut  may differ in the number of ansible_host:

Case 1, three logical, hosts three ansible_hosts

```
all:                                                                                                                          
  hosts:                                                                                                                      
    db:                                                                                                        
      ansible_host: db.example.com                                                                                                   
    apps:                                                                                                            
      ansible_host: app.example.com                                                                                                   
    proxy: 
      ansible_host: proxy.example.com
```

Case 2, three logical, hosts one ansible_host

```
all:                                                                                                                          
  hosts:                                                                                                                      
    db: &ahost                                                                                                       
      ansible_host: allinone.example.com                                                                                                   
    apps: 
      <<: *ahost
    proxy: 
      <<: *ahost
```

In my playbook there are some common tasks applicable for all,
like **yum**

```
  - name: "Install OS packages"                                                                                               
    yum: pkg={{item}} state=installed                                                                                         
    with_items:                                                                                                               
      - p1
      - p2
      - ... (quite a lot)
```

they may collide when running since ansible tries to run them in parrallel which causes yum session locks.

I wonder how can I tell ansible to skip installing os packages on *apps* and 
*proxy* once it has already started yum on *db* in Case 2.
(Other than swithcing off the parrallelism)

Comment: Why not just use groups (db/apps/proxy) in the inventory?

Comment: Erm.. What would be the point of using groups ?

Comment: Because groups are usually used to logically separate parts of playbook. But your approach with defining "different" hosts with same ansible_host is a rarely used hack when you need to handle complex inventory variable overlap scenarios. It has known drawback with concurrency problems.

Comment: I see, that generally make sense, i however could separate it logically on the host level too, calling parts apllicable to diffrent hosts likewise you suggested for groups, but for common, non-specific tasks that would be a redundant multiplicity which i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Ansible [File](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html) module. Prior to you `Install OS Packages` step, you can create a temporary file.

```
- name: "Create temporary file to lock yum"
  file:
    path: /tmp/yum.lock
    state: present
```

Next, you will create a task to check if lock file exists. We expect for it to exist, once it was created during the first connection.

```
- name: "Check if yum lock file exists"
    stat:
      path: /tmp/yum.lock
    register: yum_lock
```

Then, modify your task:

```
  - name: "Install OS packages"                                                                                               
    yum: pkg={{item}} state=installed  
    when: yum_lock.stat.exists == False                                                                                       
    with_items:                                                                                                               
      - p1
      - p2
      - ... (quite a lot)
```

Finally, add a cleanup task to remove yum lock file.

```
- name: "Delete temporary file to lock yum"
  file:
    path: /tmp/yum.lock
    state: absent
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've tried that so far with no success. It's tricky to figure out the right point of insertion lock/unlock, since they are still in the same playbook which runs in parallel ...

Comment: Can you run your playbook in `serial=1`?